How to add Word Dotx templates, for company branded documents, to all (300) company Teams programatticaly
Our customer wants a centralized document library containing all company-branded documents. They want these DOTX templates to be available in the New menu of the document libraries in all Microsoft Teams (approx 300).
I’ve found this solution:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/discussions/sharepoint_general/can-we-add-the-same-templates-on-multiple-document-libraries/3933529
However, this doesn't work across site collections. The templates appear under the New button, but when I try to open a document, it shows an "unknown error."
Basically, I need to add the same DOTX templates to all Teams, ensuring they're updated when needed. Does anyone know how to achieve this programmatically?
